# Can the region be used as a variable?

Tags: c#, preprocessor, region

I'm performing a cleanup of the database in my code. It looks as follows:

```
#region Orders and SubOrders
try
{
    ... // this code tries to remove the Orders and the SubOrders
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error($"An exception occurred while cleaning Orders and SubOrders. Error message=[{ex.Message}]");
}

#region Customers
try
{
    ... // this code tries to remove the Customers
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error($"An exception occurred while cleaning Customers. Error message=[{ex.Message}]");
}
```

Is it possible to replace the `_logger` line by something like:

```
_logger.Error($"An exception occurred while cleaning [{#currentregion}]. Error message=[{ex.Message}]");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally I despise regions in C#. Generally if you find you have to use them, then that class is almost certainly too large already and needs to be split up.

Comment: I think your problem is to split those method in 3 method because from my point of view sounds like the code that you're cleaning do alot of thing
a region is a pre compilation behavior that has nothing to do with C# code by it's self

Comment: You could take this `try { ..some code.. } catch { }` pattern you have and make a method out of it that accepts a delegate for the `some code` part and a name for that, then just call `TryAndLogAnyExceptions(() => db.Customers.Cleanup(), "Customers")` or if a Customer is ICleanable or whatever, you can just have the `TryAndLog(ICleanable x)` executor run the `x.Cleanup()` method that the interface guarantees, and interrogate the name of the db object it is cleaning up from the type etc if it fails.. Plenty of ways to skin the cat

Comment: I think this can be achieved with source generator by searching the `RegionDirectiveTrivia` forward in the syntax tree.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't. In C#, the #region directive is a feature of the C# preprocessor that allows you to group sections of code for organizational purposes in the editor, but it doesn't have any runtime presence. Once your code is compiled, the #region directives are not preserved in the compiled binary

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this using `#region`.

Possibly a better design would be to have a separate method for each of your current `#region` sections. Then you could use `nameof` to get at the name of the method to inject into the exception message:

```
void RemoveOrdersAndSubOrders()
{
    try
    {
        ... // this code tries to remove the Orders and the SubOrders
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error($"An exception occurred in {nameof(RemoveOrdersAndSubOrders)}. Error message=[{ex.Message}]");
    }
}
```

(Of course, if you were also logging the stack trace when the exception was thrown, you would already have the name of the method.)

Arguably it's a better design to split up a long method into smaller method calls anyway.

---

In response to your supplementary question:

If you have access to the Logger class you could change your `Error()` method to something like this:

```
public static void Error(
    string message,
    [CallerFilePath]   string file   = "",
    [CallerMemberName] string method = "",
    [CallerLineNumber] int    line   = 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error \"{message}\" in method \"{method}\" on line {line} of file \"{file}\"");
}
```

(Obviously you would change the `Console.WriteLine()` to whatever you're using to output the logging data.)

When you call this, you only supply the `message` parameter - the other parameters will be populated automatically.

That way when you log your errors, it will output the method name and the file path and line number.

If you don't have access to the implementation of `Error()` you could write your own `ExtendedError()` wrapper for it (possibly making it an extension method so you could call `_logger.ExtendedError("some error message");`)

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of doing this. Would much rather just put the code in different classes and the logger would automatically pick that up.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but it look overkill for the task 
using reflection just to add a name in a logger doesn't look good for me and sounds bad for performance

Comment: I'm not planning of creating a single method for every object, which needs to be cleaned, but there's another interesting thing in your answer: you state that `method` contains the name of the function you're in? Please note that currently I'm using this construction to determine the file I'm in: `{Path.GetFileName(new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true)).GetFrame(0).GetFileName())}`. Would you, by any means, have a shorter code for that?

Comment: Yeah good point about using reflection, I'll change that.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, if the code is more than a few lines then I'd put it in separate classes - but that might be overkill if each method is only a few lines.